Ubuntu 24.04 Wi-Fi hotspot doesn't work
I recently tried to enable the Wi-Fi hotspot to share my wired ethernet internet connection via wireless, so in the Wi-Fi settings I clicked on 'enable Wi-Fi Hotspot..', a window pops up asking for the hotspot name and password, but when I click Enable then nothing happens: I don't get the QR code in the Settings, the dropdown window from the top bar doesn't show Wi-Fi Hotspot, and the hotspot name doesn't show up to other devices.
I am sure the adapter works because I never had an issue connecting it to my router wireless. I searched for a similar case, but nothing seems to fit and I don't know were to start troubleshooting.

If you are using an older machine, then the issue could be due to the Wi-Fi card of this machine not being supported to create hotspot. In that case, try these steps:

Update your system.

Check the name of the Wi-Fi device using the command:
nmcli dev

This will show you the names of all network adapters.

Run this command to create a hotspot using the terminal:
nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname  ssid UbuntuRohit password 
where <yourDeviceName> and <yourPassword> are the device name you found in the previous step and your password, respectively.


If the last command shows you something like:
Invalid 'password': '32923292' is not valid WEP key (it should be 5 or 13 ASCII chars).

then try enter 0 or 1 for only 5 or 13 times. This will also show you that:
Failed to setup a Wi-Fi hotspot: Connection 'Hotspot-1' is not available on device wlp3s0 because profile is not compatible with device (the device does not support Access Point mode)

The solution to this is to try to attach a new Wi-Fi adapter and then
run:
nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname <newDeviceName> ssid UbuntuRohit password <yourPassword>

Make sure to fetch the device name by:
nmcli dev

Congratulations, you got this.
